# C++ Standard library stack usage. Trouble pushing float array

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, push

I am having trouble pushing an array to the stack. I thought this was pretty straightforward, but I've already spent too much time trying to figure this one out.

I expected to be able to push arrays just as I push ints or floats, but that is not happening.

The push command is giving me the issue. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

struct Matrix4x4
{
  float data[16];
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
// My original code
typedef std::stack<float[16]> myStack;
myStack modelViewStack;
myStack projectionStack;
float testMat[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

modelViewStack.push(testMat); // THIS LINE GIVES ME ERRORS




////Stack initialization - This is thokra's solution
////typedef std::stack<std::vector<float[16]>> myStack;
//typedef std::stack<Matrix4x4> myStack;
//myStack modelViewStack;
//myStack projectionStack;

//
//Matrix4x4 m = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
////std::vector<float> testMat2(testMat, testMat + sizeof(testMat) / sizeof(float));

//modelViewStack.push(m);

//for(int i = 0; i<16 ; i++)
//{
//  std::cout << "m data: " << m.data[i] << std::endl;
//}
//system("pause");

return 0;
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Here are the errors. I can't decipher them. Maybe an explanation of how to read these would be helpful too.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: opengl4_4, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(606): error C2075: 'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(605) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty (*),const _Ty (&))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float [16]
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(751) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty (*),const _Ty (&))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float [16]
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\type_traits(743) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float [16]
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\deque(925) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::allocator<float [16]>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stack(21) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::deque<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float [16]
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::stack<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float [16]
1>          ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(606): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: _'The last line is giving me the issue.'_ Which issue?

Comment: I added a printscreen of the error

Comment: Simply add the error text relevant for that line you're mentioning. As it is, I can't read the errors from your screenshot!

Comment: Without a complete program to compile/run/check it is impossible to see what goes wrong. You should also tell us what you see, and what you expect (and why).

Comment: Ok, will do. I'll have a complete program posted in a few minutes.

Comment: @newbie Much better now! Keep such format for future questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just encapsulate the data store holding the elements of the matrix in a suitable type:

```
#include <stack>    
struct Matrix4x4
{
  float data[16];
};

int main()
{
  typedef std::stack<Matrix4x4> myStack;
  myStack modelViewStack;
  Matrix4x4 m = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  modelViewStack.push(m);
  return 0;
}
```

More to the point: `std::stack::push` will internally call `push_back` on the `std::deque` that's used as the container when you don't change the default. Essentially, when trying to construct a new element at the end of the `deque` the container tries to place the new element at the address which currently marks the end of the container with a placement-`new`. For instance, g++ implements it as follows:

```
template<typename _Up, typename... _Args>
  void
  construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

This effectively boils down to:

```
::new((void *)__p) float[16](_args); // where __p is a pointer to float[16] and _args is testMat
```

Trying to copy- or move-initialize a C-array is simply not legal. Even if construction succeeded for some reason, the container would try to call the destructor on an element of type `float[16]` when going out of scope. One can easily see, a destructor `~T[n]` does not exist.

In C++11, you can `push` a `std::array<float,16>` instead of defining an additional type.

Comment: Changing the type of what is placed on the stack shouldn't make a difference; besides, OP presumably wants a linear array, not a matrix, for some reason.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Why do I have to encapsulate the data into a struct though? Why can't I directly make a stack of arrays? With this, I will have to access the data through the struct. Thanks.

Comment: vonbrand,

I want to to be able to store matrices and arrays. I should be able to do both, right? The reason I am using an array in this code instead of a matrix is that the template I am working off stores the openGL matrices as arrays. But if I were to implement my own code from scratch, I would use a matrix.

Anyway, I was thinking what you said - changing the type shouldn't affect the "pushability" of the stack.

Comment: @vonbrand: Nope. The OP wants to emulate the legacy OpenGL matrix stack and besides, `Matrix4x4::data` is exactly what he needs for that.

Comment: @thokra

Yeah, that's right. Thanks for your solution. I will move on with this even though I don't completely understand why it works. Ah, I just saw your edit. I will read it now.

Comment: @newbie _'Anyway, I was thinking what you said - changing the type shouldn't affect the "pushability" of the stack'_ **Trying to copy- or move-initialize a C-array is simply not legal.**